# Can keying sets be deleted in bulk?

Tags: animation

I accidentally keyframed scaling for all selected bones where only LocRot is required, is there a way to remove all scaling keys for all bones at once?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Dopesheet** or **Graph Editor**, click on the little magnifier icon on the header bar, type in "Scale" in the input field, it will allow you to filter the channel by name. Then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all channels (suppose you didn't have any customized name for other channel), <kbd>X</kbd>.

Even if you finally have some channels filtered that you do not want to delete, just try selecting or deselecting them with various selection tools, including single click. :)